# how to hide a scoll area in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to hide a scroll area but running these commands just make it smaller and more towards the bottom. I am trying to close a scroll area which has a live webcam feed in it. I have tried the hide and the close command and neither of those are working.

```
    connect(mCameraAction, &QAction::triggered, [&](){
        ui->xAxis->hide();
        ui->yAxis->hide();
        ui->zAxis->hide();
        ui->xRotate->hide();
        ui->yRotate->hide();
        ui->zRotate->hide();
        ui->x1Label->hide();
        ui->y1Label->hide();
        ui->z1Label->hide();
        ui->x2Label->hide();
        ui->y2Label->hide();
        ui->z2Label->hide();


        ui->ScrollArea->show();
        mCamera->setViewfinder(mCameraViewfinder);
        mLayout->addWidget(mCameraViewfinder);
        mLayout->setMargin(0);
        ui->ScrollArea->setLayout(mLayout);
        mCamera->start();

    });

    connect(mGantryAction,&QAction::triggered, [&](){
        mCamera->stop();
        ui->ScrollArea->hide();
        ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->hide();


        ui->xAxis->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->yAxis->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->zAxis->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->xRotate->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->yRotate->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->zRotate->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->x1Label->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->y1Label->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->z1Label->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->x2Label->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->y2Label->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->z2Label->setLayout(mLayout);
        ui->x1Label->show();
        ui->y1Label->show();
        ui->z1Label->show();
        ui->x2Label->show();
        ui->y2Label->show();
        ui->z2Label->show();
        ui->xAxis->show();
        ui->yAxis->show();
        ui->zAxis->show();
        ui->xRotate->show();
        ui->yRotate->show();
        ui->zRotate->show();


    });
```

Comment: Do not ask the same question in different publications, on one occasion you indicate that this is considered noise here

Answer (score 0):

QScrollArea is a QFrame descendant. If you set the frame shape to QFrame::NoFrame
Try :

```
setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
```